# Бинарное дерево поиска(доп информация внутри)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::endl;

std::ifstream fin("C:\\Users\\Игорь\\Desktop\\input1.txt");


struct Node
{
    int number;
    int lenght;
    string startPoint;
    string endPoint;

    Node* leftptr;
    Node* rightptr;
};


Node* GetNewNode() {    
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    fin >> newNode->number;
    fin >> newNode->lenght;
    fin >> newNode->startPoint;
    fin >> newNode->endPoint;
    newNode->leftptr = newNode->rightptr = nullptr;
    return newNode;
}


void Preorder(Node* rootptr) {
    if (rootptr == nullptr) return;
    cout << rootptr->number << " ";
    Preorder(rootptr->leftptr);
    Preorder(rootptr->rightptr);
    cout << endl;
}

Node *Insert(Node* rootptr, int number) {
    if (rootptr == nullptr) {
        rootptr = GetNewNode();
        return rootptr;
    }
    else if (number <= rootptr->number) {
        rootptr->leftptr = Insert(rootptr->leftptr, number);
    }
    else if (number>=rootptr->number) {
        rootptr->rightptr = Insert(rootptr->rightptr, number);
    }

    return rootptr;
}

int main() {
    Node* rootptr = nullptr;
    std::vector<Node>conteiner;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        conteiner.push_back(*GetNewNode());
        Insert(rootptr, conteiner[i].number);
        cout << conteiner[i].number << " ";
    }
    //Preorder(rootptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Нужно создать бинарное дерево данных для поиска по экземплярам структуры. Данные заполнения структуры читаются из файла, ключом я взял поле number, в файле оно в порядке 3 2 4 1 5. В main, в цикле, если без строки с Insert, то выводит 3 2 4 1 5 , если с Insert, то 3 4 5 0 0. Как такое может быть, если conteiner[i].number - просто передаваемый параметр. И почему если в функции Insert перед return написать cout << rootptr << " "; Ничего не выводится? Функция ведь вызывается, и cout вне всяких операторов.

UPD: ошибка, как я полагаю, в том, что я два раза вызываю GetNewNode, отсюда другой вопрос: как мне единожды создав в функции GetNewNode  узел обращаться к его полям(в Insert мне надо передать newNode->number)

Comment: "как мне единожды создав узелобращаться к его полям"... Чего? Что вам мешает обращаться к узлу после его создания? Что касается cout, то вывод буфферизирется, так что для немедленного вывода нужен \n

Comment: и как мне передать в Insert значения number?

Comment: Вы серьезно? В смысле вы реально всерьез это спрашиваете?

Comment: Да, не представляю как мне обратится к узлу. Как мне для rootptr задать адрес конкретного узла?

Comment: То что вы выделили ноду - уже хорошо, но контейнер где? Создайте контейнер для вашего дерева (а не используйте вектор). Это решит кучу проблем в вашем коде, связанных с ошибочной архитектурой. Этот код бессмысленно пытаться исправить: нужно писать заново

Comment: вектор разве не контейнер?

Comment: вы понимаете разницу разницу между массивом и деревом?

Comment: Понимаю, но не знаю какой контейнер подходит для деревьев

Comment: стоп, погодите, я думал вы пытаетесь сами написать дерево...

Comment: Я вас не понимаю, сначала вы говорите, что надо контейнер, а потом удивляетесь тому, что я хочу его использовать

Comment: итак по-порядку: 1) написать дерево и использовать готовое - это две разные вещи. 2) массив, априори, не подходит для работы с деревом (просто в виду собственной структуры). 3) контейнеры бывают разные и, не удивляйтесь, можно писать собственные!!! Так что скажите четко и ясно: вы хотите написать собственное дерево или просто использовать готовое?

Comment: Мне надо написать собственное дерево. Вектор я использовал, чтобы хранить данные для заполнения дерева.

Comment: ну так значит я не ошибся, а вот вам что не ясно? То что не нужно использовать вектор? Ну а зачем вам вектор, если вы пишите собственный контейнер?

Comment: Как мне обращаться к узлам - это все, что меня интересует

Comment: вы блин понимаете, что обращение к узлам - это логика контейнера? Который у вас не реализован... Что вы хотите чтобы вам сдесь ответили?

Comment: Как реализовать контейнер? Я работать с динамическими структурами данных начал сегодня утром, я понятия не умею о том, как реализовать контейнер и как обращаться к узлам

Comment: контейнер в данном случае - это класс хранящий корень, имеющий конструктор и деструктор, методы добавления и удаления, а также метод обращения к элементу по его ключу. Это минимум. Напишите для начала просто названия этих методов, прикинте что они должны делать, какая логика будет в них.